# Find a text cell in a range dynamically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find, cells, range

I am trying to find a cell in excel using a formula from a range.

The range will be as such:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║   ║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║ E ║ F ║ G ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ x ║ x ║ x ║ D ║ x ║ x ║ x ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

The range value will be dynamic, but it will be the same as the first row of the column it is in. So if the value were placed elsewhere in the range it would be as such:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║   ║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║ E ║ F ║ G ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ x ║ B ║ x ║ x ║ x ║ x ║ x ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

The X's represent an #N/A. 
I have a sum at the end of this, which tells me if the range contains a value, so the formula would be structured:

```
`=IF(H1= 1,#find the cell and display the value, "")`
```

H1 would be a column that shows 1 if there is a value in that range, and 0 if not.

I hope this isn't too confusing. Basically need a formula that will search the range for the value and display it. It will only contain one value, but I can't use VLookups or index matches because it's a dynamic value.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX/MATCH as an array formula:

```
=IF(H1=1,INDEX(A1:G1,MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(A1:G1)),0)),"")
```

This is **an array formula** and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  
If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]